# How can I set the size of a row in an xpage?

Tags: view, size, xpages, row

I realise this is another basic question sorry, but I can't see where to set the height of a row that is presented in an XPage.

I want to be able to set the row to a height of 3 rows (or dynamically adjust if possible).

thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Xpage control being used to generate rows, apply css styling to the control.  For a repeat control:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" 
    value="#{viewdata}" 
    var="thisRowData" 
    indexVar="thisRowIndex"
    styleClass="css-for-row">
...
</xp:repeat>
```

Apply CSS styling :

```
<style>
.css-for-row { height:3em;}
<style>
```

Or with JQuery:

```
$('.css-for-row').height('3em');
```